# How to use CAP_SYS_BOOT capability?

Tags: c, linux

I have to develop C API to shutdown linux system using reboot function through UI APPLICATION instead of system call and exec function.[This reboot link](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/reboot.2.html)says that in order to run this function caller must have the [CAP_SYS_BOOT](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) inside its user namespace.
Right now this function only work with root user I have to modified it to make it use for normal user too.**How to set sufficient privilege inside C function using capabilities in order to shutdown linux system by any user?**

```
turnoff() 
{
  sync();
  reboot(RB_POWER_OFF);
}
```

Comment: Your process had to have that capability; you can't grant it to yourself at runtime (which would defeat the whole purpose of capabilities).

Comment: So there is no way to use reboot because my UI Application is running on normal user mode.Then what is a use of CAP_SYS_BOOT ?@Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: You need to grant that capability to the executable file.

Comment: yes that I tried but here I  am trying to do same within C program

Comment: for various reasons, the `sync()` should be called twice in a row before calling anything else.   BTW: why try to use `reboot()` when the preferred method of shutting down the machine is to call `shutdown()`

Comment: for security purpose @user3629249

Answer (score 2):

Your process had to have that capability; you can't grant it to yourself at runtime (which would defeat the whole purpose of capabilities).

Read about [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html).

Use [`setcap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setcap.8.html) to set the capabilities of an executable file. This is typically done at installation time. As root:

```
setcap cap_sys_boot+ep /path/to/your/executable
```

Capabilities can also be inherited by child processes.

Comment: Yes I know about setting for executable files I thought to make inside C function thanks @Jonathon Reinhart

Comment: @raj123 If a process, running as an unprivileged user, could grant itself arbitrary capabilities, then capabilities would be completely useless as a security mechanism. Understand that what you're asking **cannot exist**.